# DIV static width wrap to new line based on browser width

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, newline

I am trying to create a DIV with a static width.  If the width exceeds the browser width, wrap to the new line.  I have tried several ways, and each of the combinations resulted in a scrollbar being added to the bottom of the browser.

For example, if I give the DIV a size of 2000x60, and the browser is 1920, I am trying to paint the 1920x60, then wrap to the next new line the remaining 80x60 pixels.

The below adds the scrollbar, how do I get this to wrap to a new line?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   #divTest{
   display:inline-block;
   width: 2000px;
   height: 60px;
   background-color: #00ffcc;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
<body>
    <div id="divTest">This is the div.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   #divTest{
    width: 1920px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #00ffcc;
   }
  #divTest2{
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #00ffcc;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divTest">This is the div.</div>
    <br>
    <div id="divTest2">This is the remainder of the div with no scrollbars.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I would like to achieve this with one dynamic div.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunally i dont get what you actually want to code.

You can use **%** or **vw** instead of **px** to make a div dynamic.

Comment: If you run the first block you will see the div will run off the screen, adding a scrollbar at the bottom because the width is greater than the width of the browser.  The second block shows what I want, where instead of adding a scroll bar, it wraps the div and continues to the next line for the remainder of the width.   I am trying to statically define the width, display what I can, by wrapping the extra that cannot fit.  I am sorry if I did not describe it well.  Thank you for looking, does that help?

Comment: Now i got it.
You can do that with JS.
You need a function wich executes on browser resize and changes the second div dynamicly.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am looking to do this with one div (The first block of code).  I would like to specify the width of a single div, and wrap appropriately if needed.  If I specify 500px it shouldn't wrap by going to the next line. If I specify 2000px it will place the 1920, and wrap the remaining 80px.  Is there a css solution for this?

Comment: Sadly CSS cant do this.